# How to abort request in phoenix-js

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Imagine: you have 1st request and some problems with it on backend/network/... Then user clicks and you have 2nd request. You don't need the result of 1st request anymore. How is it possible to abort 1st request? Like **xhr.abort**